# Variable value update scope in dart

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, flutter-web

```
    String name = "Jack";
    String aName = "John";
    if (!newChapter) {
       example....
    } else {
      http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.quran.com/api/v4/chapters/" + currentChapter)).then((result) {
        var results = json.decode(result.body);
        name = results["chapter"]["name_simple"];
        aName  = results["chapter"]["name_arabic"];
        print(name); // updated value


      });
 print(name); // default value: Jack
    }
 print(name); // default value: Jack
```

Why does the value isn't updated outside of the block?
Is there a way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is not updated is that in the else statement it's written to make an API call and update the name but before this is complete the next line of code is executed since we are not awaiting it to complete. To fix this you can add an await before the api call

```dart
await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.quran.com/api/v4/chapters/" + currentChapter)).then((result) {
        var results = json.decode(result.body);
        name = results["chapter"]["name_simple"];
        aName  = results["chapter"]["name_arabic"];
        print(name); // updated value
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the inner `print(name)` is printed after the `http request` is successfully made i.e the `then` part of the `http.get` `promise`

Whereas , the outer `print(name)` is not waiting for the `http request` to complete
To overcome this you can use one of the following methods

To overcome this you can use either of 3 methods:

1. `callback function`
2. `promise`
3. `async/await`

The `async/await` is simple and preferred to be used , hence use the following code:

```
 await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.quran.com/api/v4/chapters/" + currentChapter)).then((result) {
        var results = json.decode(result.body);
        name = results["chapter"]["name_simple"];
        aName  = results["chapter"]["name_arabic"];
        print(name); // updated value
      });
```